# Synchronizing go routines in a round-based game

Tags: go, synchronization, goroutine

I am totally new to Go and I am trying to code a game as an exercise.

Basically the main flux will create `totalNumberOfPlayers` routines, each of them will perform some tasks following a round-based game. At the end of each round a player is removed from the game until only one player remains.

In order to make sure the routines are synchronized in the same round I am trying to use a `WaitGroup` as follows:

```
func main() {
    // ... initialization code

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < totalNumberOfPlayers; i++ {
        go routineJob(i, ..., &wg)
    }
    // TODO Temporary workaround to let the main flux wait
    fmt.Scanln()
}
```

Each routine runs the same job:

```
func routineJob(routineId int, ..., wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    // ... 
    for round := 0; round < totalNumberOfPlayers-1; round++ {
        numberOfPlayers := totalNumberOfPlayers - round
        wg.Add(1) // Add player to round
        // ... perform some tasks
        if ... { // Player verifies condition to be removed from the game
            wg.Done() // Remove player from round
            return
        } 
        // ... perform some other tasks
        wg.Done() // Remove player from round
        wg.Wait() // Wait for all players to be removed before going to the next round
    }
}
```

But at the end of the first round I get the following error:

> panic: sync: WaitGroup is reused before previous Wait has returned

Looking around online I figured out that probably the problem is that after calling `wg.Wait()` I am not allowed to call `wg.Add(1)`. If that is the case, **how can I implement a round based game** like this?

**Note:** I was thinking to create an external `WaitGroup` for each round, but that would require me to create another loop somehow in the `main()` function and I would prefer to avoid this to keep the structure of the code mostly as presented.

Comment: No, the panic means you are not allowed to all `Wait` before the previous `Wait` has returned, i.e. you cannot call it from multiple goroutines concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you misunderstand about what sync.WaitGroup used for. Check [this](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/)

> A WaitGroup waits for a collection of goroutines to finish.

When using sync.WaitGroup, I would recommend you add 1 right before using go func() and add defer to mark it as finish right after using go func().

Let assume you are using go routine in main to call `routineJob`. So you need to add sync.WaitGroup here first to let your main wait all goroutines finish.

```
func main() {
// ... initialization code

var wg sync.WaitGroup
for i := 0; i < totalNumberOfPlayers; i++ {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(){
        // we add 1 for each loop and when the job finish, defer will run which mark added one done. 
        defer wg.Done()
        routineJob(i, ...)
    }()
}
wg.Wait()
// no need your work around any more. 
fmt.Scanln()
```

For your routineJob. If there is any go routine that you want to wait, you can apply as the same as above.

```
func routineJob(routineId int, ...) {
    for round := 0; round < totalNumberOfPlayers-1; round++ {
        var wg sync.WaitGroup // I assume that you need a list of funcs running in go routine here.
        wg.Add(1) 
        go func() {
          defer wg.Done()
          // Do your logic....
          return
        }()
        // your go routine 2 
        wg.Add(1) 
        go func() {
          defer wg.Done()
          // Do your logic....
          return
        }()
        wg.Wait() // Wait for all players to be removed before going to the next roundx
    }
}
```